# sum sequence nonnegative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to show the following:

If we have a convergent sum of nonnegative numbers $a_i$, then show that there exists a sequence of nonnegative numbers strictly monotone increasing positive $b_i$ where $b_i$ converging to $\infty$ such that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{a_i  b_i} < \infty\quad?$$

Thank you

Comment: This is not too hard. What have you tried so far?

Comment: if you could do it congrats, can you show? but i couldnt figure out i thought about abel transformation classix sum tests but couldnt do it..

Comment: Here's a hint: If each $b_i$ is less than $1$, then the sum converges.

Comment: of course not b_i must go to infinity..

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Since
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$
converges,
$A_n = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k \to 0$

Choose another sequence
$B_n$ which converges to zero
more slowly than $A_n$
and define $b_n$
in terms of $B_n$.

Comment: more explanation please marty..

Answer (score -1):

If the sum converges, then
$$
\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{a_{i + 1}}{a_i} = c < 1
$$
Take $b_i = c^{-i/2}$, so $b_i \to \infty$, while
$$
\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{a_{i + 1} b_{i + 1}}{a_i b_i} = c^{1/2} < 1
$$

Comment: Nope. Let $a_n = (2+(-1)^n)/n^2$. Convergent but not monotone.

Comment: marty is right...